# Running into problems trying to iterate through API data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to iterate through an array returned from an AJAX call to log relevant data for my program.

When I `console.log(response.data.url)`, all  the relevant data is returned. However, I need to push this data into an array so I can use it later. I initiated a `for` loop within the function, but when I check the console it returns an error message saying

> url is undefined

I'm not sure where the error is coming from since the first `console.log` before the function works properly. Im new to programming.
My code is below:

```
function callAJAX() {
  $.ajax({
    url: userSearchURL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data.url)
    for (i = 0; i <= response.data.length; i++) {
       console.log(response.data[i].url)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: In one case you're logging `response.data.url`, in the other `response.data[i].url`. You should edit the question to show the format of the data you're receiving.

Comment: If `response.data.url` returns you the URL then `response.data` is not an array, so you cannot iterate through it.

Comment: @vlaz is right, you are not returning an array, you are accessing the first level of an object, response.data.length is undefined since an Object doesn't have "length" property

Comment: As a side note, even if `response.data` WAS an array, you shouldn't do `i <= response.data.length` in your for loop because that would lead to an off-by-one error with the indexing. Since array indexes start at zero, an array with three elements would have a last index of two, so when `i = length` you'd get `arr[3]` which, in turn, will probably blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's going on here is that you have an object with keys. In order to iterate over your object, like an array, you need to take advantage of the built-in `Object.keys()` function. Try something like this instead of your `for` loop:

```
Object.keys(response.data).forEach(dataKey => {
  console.log(response.data[dataKey])
});
```

Comment: Also, how would I stop the loop after a certain number of iterations? Right now it runs through the entire data set but I only need the first 15 values returned?

Comment: Since the code above goes through each element in the new array created by `Object.keys()`, instead you could make a new variable `let array = Object.keys(response.data)`, then you can just treat like an array. So you can now use a for loop with `i` being less than either the max array length or 15, whichever is greater. I would do something like: `for(let i = 0; i < (array.length <= 15 ? array.length : 15); i++)` **Note:** my example uses a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)